# Validating zip code with regex and selenium

Tags: c#, regex

So with selenium I am able to grab some of the addresses of the users 
For ex:
4034 Wells Branch, San Francisco CA 34123

Is there a method I could use to make sure the zip code given is  5 digits?

Comment: `(\d\d\d\d\d)` ?

Comment: Please post any attempts or research you have done.

Comment: @Dai No... google it.

Comment: Removed Selenium tag since this has nothing to do with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for instance, we can define a group as a right boundary and include what might make it non-five-digits, such as `(?:[^-0-9])`, and our expression can be:

```
\b([0-9]{5})\b(?:[^-0-9])
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/FGymiV/1/)

Or we would add a right boundary that are valid with 5-digits zip codes only, such as:

```
\b([0-9]{5})\b(?:\s|$)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/2uMNGP/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\b([0-9]{5})\b(?:\s|$)";
        string input = @"4034 Wells Branch, San Francisco CA 34123
4034 Wells Branch, San Francisco CA 34123-
4034 Wells Branch, San Francisco CA 34123-1234
4034 Wells Branch, San Francisco CA 341231234";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]